# Why PHP cannot send mail from test@test.com?

Tags: php, email

This doesn't work:

```
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$from = 'test@test.com';
$subj = 'test';
$message = 'hello';

$headers =  "From: {$from}\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: {$from}\r\n";
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$response['success'] = mail($to, $subj, $message, $headers);
```

This does:

```
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$from = 'bill@gates.com';
$subj = 'test';
$message = 'hello';

$headers =  "From: {$from}\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: {$from}\r\n";
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$response['success'] = mail($to, $subj, $message, $headers);
```

The mail function doesn't seem to work with test@test.com, is there a reason for this ?

Thank you

Comment: Notice: test@test2.com doesn't work, test2@test.com works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because test.com has an SPF record which indicates that it doesn't send email:

```
test.com.       7200    IN  TXT "v=spf1 ~all"
```

This would likely lead GMail to reject (or flag as spam) any mail claiming to be from test.com.

Alternatively, GMail may have an explicit block on test@test.com. :)

Comment: how did you get the zone file?

Answer (score 0):

test2.com is not a valid domain name.MTA probably refuse to relay your message because of that.

If you turn on error_reporting, are you receive any warning?